# White spots on cactus

Tags: diseases, cactus

I’m fairly new to gardening but purchased some cactus’ last year. I noticed one started to develop a white spot on the side of it. I isolated this cactus into its own pot. Any idea’s what it is or what can be done to possibly cure it?

Other info:

1. I live in Texas.
2. The cactus is typically outside unless it is too cold or it is going to rain.
3. I water it once a month, unless it rains enough.

Thanks in advance!

~ Colin

[image: Cactus]

Comment: Did you move it too soon to direct sunlight? Anyway, a sunburn or frostbite won't spread. It can still grow, flower and provide new cuttings and seeds.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like sunburn, given the strength of the sun in Texas. See the link below. The plant also looks overpotted (pot too large for the plant). You may want to repot to a smaller pot, water it a bit more often, and offer it some protection from prolonged sunlight. Hope this helps.

http://www.cactiguide.com/article/article4.php

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. I’m going to repot it in a smaller pot and then get it in a location where it’s not exposed to the sun for as long during the day.

Comment: In my experience place plants so they get full sun during most of the day, but are in shadows in the afternoon. If the plant is kept well watered it will also resist sunburn (some species more than others). The pot size has nothing to do with your sunburn.